# Drupal 7 get dropdown list selected value

Tags: drupal

I have the following code that creates a dropdown list from my database :

```
  foreach( $aPlayers as $player ){
   if( $_SESSION['player'] == $player->iPlayer ){
     $playerSelected = $player->iPlayer;
   }
   $key = $player->iPlayer;
   $value = ucfirst($player->sName);
   $playersList[$key] = $value;
  }
  $form['gestionvideos_player']['selectplayer'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => $playersList,
   '#default_value' => $playerSelected,
  );
```

But then when I try to submit my form and get user's selected value with :

```
function gestionvideos_players_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   echo $form_state['values']['selectplayer'];
}
```

The return value is not the one selected.

Do you have any idea to help me?

Thank you :)

Comment: what is the return value ? also can u share your link

Comment: The return value is the one that is by default in the database, but not the one selected in the dropdown list... What link do you want me to share?